# Pythonic way to assign most common outcome in a group to the entire group

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have two predictors, `A` and `B`, and an outcome, `outcome`, in my pandas data frame, `df`.
I want to assign the most common outcome in each `A` + `B` group to a new column, `prediction`.

For example, in the `df` below, when `A` is 1 and `B` is 0, `outcome` is more likely to be -1.
As a result, I would like to assign -1 to `prediction` every time `A` is 1 and `B` is 0.

The code below works but seems very un-Pythonic.
Is there a better way to perform this series of operations?

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'A' : 10*[0] + 10*[1], 'B' : 10*[0,1], 'outcome' : 15*[-1] + 5*[1]})

df

df.groupby(['A', 'B', 'outcome']).size()

temp = df.groupby(['A', 'B', 'outcome']).size().reset_index()
temp.columns = ['A', 'B', 'outcome', 'count']
temp.sort_values(['A', 'B', 'count'], inplace=True, ascending=False)
temp2 = temp[['A', 'B', 'outcome']].drop_duplicates(subset=['A', 'B'])
temp2.rename({'outcome':'prediction'}, inplace=True, axis=1)

temp2

pd.merge(df, temp2, on=['A', 'B'])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us try `transform` with `mode`

```
s=df.groupby(['A','B']).outcome.transform(lambda x : x.mode()[0])
0    -1
1    -1
2    -1
3    -1
4    -1
5    -1
6    -1
7    -1
8    -1
9    -1
10   -1
11    1
12   -1
13    1
14   -1
15    1
16   -1
17    1
18   -1
19    1
Name: outcome, dtype: int64
df['Fq']=s
```